# Installing condor on RHEL7

Tags: rhel7, condor

I am trying to install condor on RHEL7. I did this:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
sudo wget http://htcondor.org/yum/repo.d/condor-stable-rhel7.repo
sudo wget http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor//yum/repo.d/htcondor-stable-rhel7.repo
sudo wget http://htcondor.org/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-HTCondor
sudo rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-HTCondor
sudo yum install condor-all
```

The install seemed to work, but I have no /etc/condor dir and I cannot find any of the condor files.

What is the proper way to install condor?

Comment: The news page https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/new.html says that SELinux was causing problems on Red Hat 7.4 .  Which version do you have?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. One package was getting `Package c-ares-1.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm is not signed` and that was preventing the install. I did the install with `--nogpgcheck` and it worked.